# How to call a specific node for a class in D3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is driving me crazy. Here is the code where I want to enter a specific class for each node. So here it assigns all nodes the "node" class but then I want to somehow force the first node to be assigned  "node1" or something. I have been playing around with (d, i) but it's not working.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/issyhjg/7o03oqaw/) I've been working with

```
   //add nodes and effects
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")        
    .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("class", "node")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply node classes or ids as a function of your data:

Instead of this:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")        
    .attr("class", "node")
```

which applies the same class to all nodes, as noted, you could use something like:

```
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")        
    .attr("class", function(d,i) {return  "node-" + i; })
```

Here i is equal to the current node's place in the data array. So you will have classes like: `node-0`, `node-1`, `node-2`... The d refers to the data being bound to the node, and you can access its properties by using d.property.

Thus, you could use a property of your data to define a class or id:

```
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")        
    .attr("class", function(d) { return  "node-" + d["property"]; })
```

or

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")        
    .attr("class", function(d) { return  "node-" + d.property; })
```